# Active record query WHERE CLAUSE has empty value or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What's the best practice to query an active record where you don't know that value will be empty or not.

So, in my view, I have this form to send a query on a controller for querying

```
   <%= form_tag("/worksteps", method: "get") do %>
    <div>
      <span>Work Steps</span>
      <%= label_tag(:attrib, "All") %>
        <%# "is not null" is a hack to query all %>
      <%= radio_button_tag(:attrib, "is not null", checked = true ) %>
        <%# workstep_attrib are the column names %>
      <% @workstep_attrib.each do |attrib| %>
      <%= label_tag(:attrib, attrib.name) %>
        <%# value is a hack it will render "= 21" %>
      <%= radio_button_tag(:attrib, "= #{attrib.id}") %> 
      <%end%>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= label_tag :dent_case, 'Search Case'%>
      <%= text_field_tag :dent_case%>
      <%= submit_tag :search%>
    </div>
  <%end%>
```

`<%= radio_button_tag(:attrib, "is not null", checked = true ) %>`
a hack that I made to query everything

`<%= radio_button_tag(:attrib, "= #{attrib.id}") %>`
a hack also to query a specific column

And this is what I got on my controller

// since first load is empty

```
 if !params[:attrib]
          params[:attrib] = "is not null"
 end
```

// query code, where clause is funky

```
Spree::WorkorderProductWorkstep.includes(product_workstep: [:workstep],                                          
                                                            workorder: [:product,
                                                            denture_design: [:denture_design_spec],
                                                            order: [:user]])
                                                                            .where("spree_worksteps.id #{params[:attrib]}")
                                                                            .references(:workstep)
```

Is their another way? I'm also aware that the security risk on where clause where I'm not sanitizing incoming data but that's not my priority for now.

## Update

I also added this ugly solution on a same query

```
 if !params[:dent_case] || params[:dent_case].empty?
          params[:dent_case] = "is not null"
        else 
          params[:dent_case] = "= #{params[:dent_case]}"
        end
```

`.where("denture_designs.id #{params[:dent_case]}")`

Comment: Not sure if I got your question right, but perhaps this is what you are looking for: https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try.

Comment: not that sir but thanks. what im trying to do is query with a where condition. lets say an ID. i have to pass `= params[:attrib]` (equals) so it will query if I give it a number if no value or number i just have to `params[:attrib] is not null`